# Filter criteria keyboard shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-datagrip

Having IntelliJ Ultimate / Datagrip when I go to the editor of table's data (**Database** tab -> **schemas** -> selected schema -> **tables** -> `F4` upon selected table) I am able to provide "filter criteria" to the input field above data view by selecting "Filter by" option from context menu upon a cell. However after applying a filter criteria which doesn't return any rows I can't revoke them otherwise than clicking on "times" icon using mouse.

Is it possible to gain focus on that input field or clear current filter criterias by using keyboard only?

Looking at keymap in settings I couldn't get any hint on how to get there.

Comment: Have you tried Alt+Shift+Cmd(Ctrl)+F? See **Edit Filter Criteria** action.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, it has no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had try ctrl+Shift+Alt+F, but not works, I think there may have some conflict with windows shortcut. So I set up the manual.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moove.png)
I use Shift+F , and it's can works.

Comment: It resolved the root cause of my problem - overlooking a keymap's entry handling the feature. Thanks for pointing it out!